# How to format JSON value and display in datagridview

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, json-deserialization

In my asp.net web API, JSON string return as follows.

```
[
  {
    "Company": "Company A",
    "ProjectName": "Project A",
    "Developer": "No developer assigned",
    "Hour": 0,
    "Overtime": 0,
    "Contribution": "0"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company A",
    "ProjectName": "Project B",
    "Developer": "paul",
    "Hour": 36,
    "Overtime": 27,
    "Contribution": "71.5909%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company A",
    "ProjectName": "Project B",
    "Developer": "kalpa",
    "Hour": 16,
    "Overtime": 9,
    "Contribution": "28.4091%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company B",
    "ProjectName": "Project C",
    "Developer": "shane",
    "Hour": 40,
    "Overtime": 14,
    "Contribution": "78.2609%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company B",
    "ProjectName": "Project C",
    "Developer": "kal",
    "Hour": 10,
    "Overtime": 5,
    "Contribution": "21.7391%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company C",
    "ProjectName": "Project D",
    "Developer": "No developer assigned",
    "Hour": 0,
    "Overtime": 0,
    "Contribution": "0"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company D",
    "ProjectName": "Project E",
    "Developer": "No developer assigned",
    "Hour": 0,
    "Overtime": 0,
    "Contribution": "0"
  }
]
```

when I consume my API on my C# desktop app and display that JSON string as following image:

[image]

This is my C# desktop application code to display JSON object in `datagridview` in the `setGrid` method,which take JSON object as parameter and display it on `datgridview`.

```
public void setGrid(string obj)
{
    try
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = json;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

But I need to display this result as following image. I need to merge company column for same values. This image shows expected result:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: it's simple. put the deserialized json into a `List<dynamic>`  and then use the `groupby()` from `System.Linq` to group the results from a collection.

Comment: @iam.Carrot sir can you give me a sample code here as answer.please

Comment: Yeah working on it :) I just gave you the hint so that you can look for it in the mean time

Comment: @iam.Carrot sure I'll try, but I really expect your help and answer,thank in advanced

Comment: Quick question, do you have to use `List<Dynamic>` or you can create a `Class` that can act as a `Model`

Comment: @iam.Carrot It doesn't matter. I need to solve this however. :) please give me easiest solution sir :)

Comment: last question are you using `MVVM` or something like that? Main question is, please share your `XAML` code or are you using `WinForms`

Comment: @iam.Carrot sorry, I'm not clear your question sir,please excuse. I new to c# and ASP.net web api

Comment: okay so what is your platform? is it `WinForms` or `WPF` what is it? Do you have `XAML` designer

Comment: @iam.Carrot I am using winForms sir. no I dont have XAMl designer

Comment: @iam.Carrot i develop my api as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVUUhlLB0sI

and I consume it as this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/http-request-methods-get-post-put-and-delete/

withing the consume part. I create this setGrid method and passed json object to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after seeing the image, the Task seem to be the need for `System.Linq`. You will first need to group your data.

I've created a method that provides me the `JSON` that you've mentioned.

```
public static IEnumerable<ProjectInfo> GetResponse()
{
        IEnumerable<ProjectInfo> items = new List<ProjectInfo>();
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Data.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectInfo>>(json);
        }
        return items;
}
```

The `ProjectInfo` class is defined as below:

```
public class ProjectInfo
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Developer { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Overtime { get; set; }
    public string Contribution { get; set; }
}
```

Now getting to the code, Using `System.Linq` group your `list` on the `Company` property

```
var APIResponse = GetResponse();

var grouped = APIResponse.GroupBy(x => x.Company);
```

Now you have a grouped collection. Use the below Template as the `GridView`

```
protected override void OnCellPainting(
DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs args)
{
   base.OnCellPainting(args);

   args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom =
   DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;

   // Ignore column and row headers and first row
   if (args.RowIndex < 1 || args.ColumnIndex < 0)
      return;

   if (IsRepeatedCellValue(args.RowIndex, args.ColumnIndex))
   {
       args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top =
       DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
   }
   else
   {
       args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
   }
}
```

---

Sources:

[Link 1](https://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx)
[Link 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44622c0-74e1-463b-97b9-27b87513747e/windows-forms-data-controls-and-databinding-faq?forum=winformsdatacontrols#faq8)
[Link 3](https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupby)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this sir. I am really appreciate for your consecration

Comment: I hope this helps. Let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: where should I add these lines sir? `var APIResponse = GetResponse();

var grouped = APIResponse.GroupBy(x => x.Company);`

Comment: Replace the getResponse() with your method that returns you the list from the API.

Comment: Please note the GetResponse() is reading JSON from a file ( in your case it'll be an API) then it uses the nugget JSON.net (newtonsoft.json) to parse the JSON to a collection.

Comment: Sir please this my question and help me. yesterday I I tried this.but not solved, so please check this and help me to solve

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940589/how-to-pass-formated-json-string-using-asp-net-web-api