# Create a grouped `DataGridView` Windows Form application

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I developed ASP.net web API, which returns JSON in this format.

```
[
  {
    "Company": "Company A",
    "ProjectName": "Project A",
    "Developer": "No developer assigned",
    "Hour": 0,
    "Overtime": 0,
    "Contribution": "0"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company A",
    "ProjectName": "Project B",
    "Developer": "paul",
    "Hour": 36,
    "Overtime": 27,
    "Contribution": "71.5909%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company A",
    "ProjectName": "Project B",
    "Developer": "kalpa",
    "Hour": 16,
    "Overtime": 9,
    "Contribution": "28.4091%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company B",
    "ProjectName": "Project C",
    "Developer": "shane",
    "Hour": 40,
    "Overtime": 14,
    "Contribution": "78.2609%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company B",
    "ProjectName": "Project C",
    "Developer": "kal",
    "Hour": 10,
    "Overtime": 5,
    "Contribution": "21.7391%"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company C",
    "ProjectName": "Project D",
    "Developer": "No developer assigned",
    "Hour": 0,
    "Overtime": 0,
    "Contribution": "0"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Company D",
    "ProjectName": "Project E",
    "Developer": "No developer assigned",
    "Hour": 0,
    "Overtime": 0,
    "Contribution": "0"
  }
]
```

when I consume this on c# windows form application to display JSON and this output will be displayed.

[image]

but this my required output,so I need to change this JSON format to take this output as this image. So how can I do it using ASP.net web API

[image]

In my web API,This is the part of my model class call Company.

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Developer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Hour { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Overtime { get; set; }
    public string Contribution { get; set; }
}
```

This part of my controller class called CompanyController

```
namespace DeleteAPI.Controllers
{    
    public class CompanyController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Company
        public ArrayList Get()
        {
            CompanyPersistent tp = new CompanyPersistent();
            return tp.getCompanyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of CompanyPersistent class.

```
public class CompanyPersistent
{
    public ArrayList getCompanyAll()
    {
        ArrayList stdArray = new ArrayList();
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader mySQLReader = null;

        try
        {
            string sqlString = "select * from tblCompany";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
            mySQLReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (mySQLReader.Read())
            {
                CompanyModel dm = new CompanyModel();
                dm.Company = mySQLReader.GetString(0);
                dm.ProjectName = mySQLReader.GetString(1);
                dm.Developer = mySQLReader.GetString(2);
                dm.Hour = mySQLReader.GetInt32(3);
                dm.Overtime = mySQLReader.GetInt32(4);
                dm.Contribution = mySQLReader.GetString(5);
                stdArray.Add(dm);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Number);
        }
        return stdArray;
    }
}
```

**Updated**:

This is how I generate table using C# windows form application, withing the consume part I pass this JSON string to setGrid(string obj) method. and display it on dataGridView

```
public void setGrid(string obj)
{
    try
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = json;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

[Link to the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ym7caXowFHph4lNJZIXeMppykToVKNKI/view)

Comment: I looks a issue about how to show on table instead of format json. How are you generating the table?

Comment: @RicardoPontual I updated my question

Comment: But it's missing the table generation. It can be simple to group the row with same json, but we need to understand how are the table being generated

Comment: @RicardoPontual please check now sir, someone edited my answer and missed my code what i updated

Comment: you need to share the `OnCellPainting` method show the entire thing. from `Datapulling` to `TableCreation`

Comment: @iam.Carrot In my project there is no `OnCellPainting` method

Comment: it's a `WinForms` project right?

Comment: @iam.Carrot yes sir

Comment: so share the code where you define the `GridView` and where you've defined the gridview to merge cells

Comment: @iam.Carrot this is my complete c# consume windows form app, this gives me this output (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrEgv.png) data load to datagridview properly 

this is complete windows form app
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ym7caXowFHph4lNJZIXeMppykToVKNKI

Comment: Can you put the code on `Githib`? Because see a lot of people are quite conscious while downloading `.zip` files

Comment: @iam.Carrot this time I'm unable to upload it to Git. so If you can please help me sir. & this is not WPF. this is windows form

Comment: yeah it's `WinForms` in my edit I've mentioned the same

Comment: @iam.Carrot sir can you give me an answer please